# Describe an algorithm to determine if the same discovery/finishing times are possible in a new DFS run with a new edge

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, depth-first-search

You are given a directed graph `G = (V,E)` and a DFS forest with the discovery/finishing times of every vertex after a DFS run. Suppose a new edge e is now added to G. With the old discovery and finishing times being available at `O(1)`, describe an efficient algorithm to determine if the same discovery/finishing times are possible in a new DFS run on `G'=(V,E+e)`.

First, I think that if e connects 2 previously unconnected components then it wouldn't be possible since the discovery time of any vertex in the component that was discovered after the first would be later than any finishing time of the first component, which can no longer be the case.
Next, I think that if the vertex u that e is entering is discovered by the vertex v that e is leaving, then the discovery/finish time of some vertex must change. Not sure how to prove this though.
So I think that v and u must be in the same tree and that u.d < v.d, but I'm not sure and I can't think of a way to prove/disprove it.

If it's correct, I think you can check if there is a vertex w such that d.w < d.v < d.w < f.w to verify both the above conditions apply in `O(V)` time. But I have a feeling I'm not on the right track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For ease of referring to the elements included in the problem statement, let's assume that the edge is labeled as `e`, and that it connects two vertices `u` and `v`. I will refer to the discover and finish times of any vertex `w` as `w.d` and `w.f`, respectively.

There are four possible cases of timing in terms of the discover and finish times of `u` and `v`. I believe the answer will be clear if each such case is considered separately.

First, let's consider the case where `u.d < v.d < v.f < u.f`. This order can occur if v is a child or an indirect descendant of u in the initial graph `G`. In this case, depending on how you store and traverse through the graph structure, adding `e` *may* result in the same discovery and finish times. In other words, the DFS can still use the old edges first, and end up with the same discovery/finish times. `e` will then be processed only as an extra back or forward edge, which does not affect the resulting discovery/finish times.

The second case is where `u.d < u.f < v.d < v.f`. In this setup, after `e` is added to the initial graph, as `u` will have `v` as a direct child, due to the exhaustive children-first processing strategy of the DFS algorithm, the `v.d` and `v.f` values will be updated to inevitably become smaller than `u.f`. In this case, there is no possibility of retaining the initial discovery/finish values, and they will be altered, regardless of whether they are in the same connected component.

The third and fourth cases are the reflection of the first two, with the `u`s and `v`s swapped. (i.e., `v.d < u.d < u.f < v.f` and `v.d < v.f < u.d < u.f`) You can extend the explanation for the first two cases to cover these as well.

After this consideration, the algorithm you are looking for is rather trivial to construct. You have the discovery and finish times available to you in `O(1)`, and it appears that you also know the `u` and `v` vertices connected by `e`. You can simply check the initial discovery and finish times of `u` and `v`. If they match the first or the third case, then the discovery/finish times after `e` is added *can* still be the same. If they match the second or the fourth case, then the times will certainly change after a second DFS run.

Since you are doing a constant amount of checks regardless of the size of the graph, the algorithm would take `O(1)` time and use `O(1)` extra space.

Comment: Thanks, makes much more sense.